# How to read n lines from a file in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to read first n lines from a file using clojure. Here is my code:

```
(defn read-nth-line [file]
  (with-open [rdr (reader file)]
    (loop [line-number 0]
      (when (< line-number 20)
            (nth (line-seq rdr) line-number)
            (recur (inc line-number))))))
```

but when I run

```
 user=> (read-nth-line "test.txt")

 IndexOutOfBoundsException   clojure.lang.RT.nthFrom (RT.java:871)
```

I have no idea why I got such an error.

Comment: Does `test.txt`contain more than 20 lines?

Comment: Can you add the require to your question? I like being able to copy paste code into the REPL: (require '[clojure.java.io :refer [reader]])

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code produces an out-of-bounds error because you call `line-seq` multiple times on the same reader. If you want to get a number of lines from a reader, you should call `line-seq` only once, then take the desired number of lines from that sequence:

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn lines [n filename]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (doall (take n (line-seq rdr)))))
```

Example:

```
(run! println (lines 20 "test.txt"))
```

If `test.txt` contains fewer than 20 lines, this will simply print all the lines in the file.

Comment: Can you add the require to your answer? I like being able to copy paste code into the REPL

(require '[clojure.java.io :refer [reader]])

Comment: @MichielBorkent Sure; I was just trying to mirror the OP's style. I added a `require` with an alias, because I prefer to use `:as` over `:refer` when feasible.